# Removing unwanted fields when extending Django UserCreationForm

Tags: django, django-forms

Just started getting into Django and have become stuck when extending the classic UserRegistrationForm. I have followed the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaPHSlTmg1s) which is great, but the Html form in the browser shows me fields I do not want. I only want to extend **email** for now, but want to add First Name and surname later.

Please note I have no CSS yet, just want to see the basic information in the browser for now. Can anybody explain why I am seeing all the other fields in addition to **username**, **password**, **password2** and **email**?

[image]

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm): 
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        field = ('username','email','first_name','last_name','password1', 'password2')

def save(self, commit=True)
    user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email'] #validated before committing to database

    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response #allows you to render a template back to the browser
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect #allows the browser to redirect to another url
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf # method to stop hackers submitting requests
from fantasymatchday_1.forms import MyRegistrationForm #A user registration form I created that inherits the UserCreationForm

def register_user(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST) #create a form object
           if form.is_valid(): #if the form is valid, save the form
              form.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/register_success')

        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))

        args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
        #print args
        return render_to_response('register.html', args)

def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('register_success.html')
```

**register.html**

```
   <h2> Register </h2>

   <form action="/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   {{form}}

   <input type="submit" value="Register" />

   </form>
```

Why are all the others turning up? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `MyRegistrationForm`'s `Meta` definition:

```
field =  ('username','email','first_name','last_name','password1', 'password2')
```

It should be `fields` rather than `field`.